# iOS automatic update notification

Tags: ios, app-store

I have been looking for this answer but I can't find something clear.

On iOS, if I submit an update of my app on iTunesConnect, does the AppStore will automatically show a red bubble and my app will be shown in the update section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will appear as an update to everyone that has your app installed when the update is approved by Apple and you release it. So yes, the App Store app will display that there is an update, display the red bubble and it will be shown in the update section. But first the update needs to go through the review process.